# Running into segmentation fault error via Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, computer-vision

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from PIL import Image

stimuli = cv2.imread('/Users/person/Downloads/face.png')

grayim = 127*np.ones_like(stimuli)

#top of face image covered
grayim[120:,:,:] = stimuli[120:,:,:]
plt.imshow(grayim)
plt.show()
```

Python opens a preview file for a split second before crashing -- the error I'm receiving is zsh: segmentation fault  /Users/person/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/person/image.py

What changes should I make? Still a bit new to image manipulation and processing :) trying to cover upper third of a face and mask the bottom with a grayscale image with the same shape/dimensions. Also, I tried using Image.open instead of cv2.imread and end up with a 'TypeError: 'PngImageFile' object is not subscriptable' error at `grayim[120:,:,:] = stimuli[120:,:,:]`

Comment: Please give us some idea what part of the code causes the segfault?

Comment: @JodyKlymak There's no traceback clue as to what part, but I'm thinking it's the plt.show(). Also, I tried using Image.open instead of cv2.imread but the error is 'grayim[120:,:,:] = stimuli[120:,:,:]
TypeError: 'PngImageFile' object is not subscriptable'

Comment: @marklees can you share the image you are testing on as according to me it should not have any issue.

Comment: So if you return before you plot matplotlib there is no segfault?  You don’t have to guess. You just keep adding lines of code until it segfaults.